# RoyalSlider overflow is visible IE 10

Tags: jquery, css, slider, internet-explorer-10

I am creating a slideshow using [Royal Slider](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/) but its misbehaving in IE10 ONLY.

I have created a fiddle to show the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/vwDFa/6/.

Hover over the slide, drag over to the next slide and come back to the first slide. As you come back the overflow is visible for a second(its hard to see it the first time). IE10 is the only browser that does this.

this pic shows what happens on my site in IE10 (overflow visible after the blue arrows):
[image: IE10 bug]

**Markup** (sorry for the long code, i trimmed it as much as possible):

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="royalSlider heroSlider rsMinW rsHor rsWithBullets" id="full-width-slider">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="news-feed-item" style="border-left-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); border-left-width: 1px; border-left-style: solid;">
                <div class="news-data">
                    <div class="title text-when-feed">Stay Classy: Watch our one-on-one with <i>Anchorman 2</i>'s Will Ferrell</div>
                    <div class="overflow" style="margin: 0px; border-radius: 0px; border: 0px rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 212px; height: 100px; overflow: hidden; float: none; position: relative;">
                        <div class="description text-when-feed" style="margin: 0px; border: 0px currentColor; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100px; overflow: auto; padding-right: 24px;">
                            <div class="ExternalClassFC1894FA843E4EEABAFC80CA39E45A4B"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="news-feed-item">
                <div class="news-data">
                    <div class="title text-when-feed">Stay Classy: Watch our one-on-one with <i>Anchorman 2</i>'s Will Ferrell</div>
                    <div class="overflow" style="margin: 0px; border-radius: 0px; border: 0px rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 212px; height: 100px; overflow: hidden; float: none; position: relative;">
                        <div class="description text-when-feed" style="margin: 0px; border: 0px currentColor; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100px; overflow: auto; padding-right: 24px;">
                            <div class="ExternalClass803AEC05C6824A5788848654FE955202"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="news-feed-item">
                <div class="news-data">
                    <div class="title text-when-feed">Stay Classy: Watch our one-on-one with <i>Anchorman 2</i>'s Will Ferrell</div>
                    <div class="overflow" style="margin: 0px; border-radius: 0px; border: 0px rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 212px; height: 100px; overflow: hidden; float: none; position: relative;">
                        <div class="description text-when-feed" style="margin: 0px; border: 0px currentColor; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100px; overflow: auto; padding-right: 24px;">
                            <div class="ExternalClass932B501F43114EC09931584B98E42717"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="news-feed-item" style="border-left-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); border-left-width: 1px; border-left-style: solid;">
                <div class="news-data">
                    <div class="title text-when-feed">Stay Classy: Watch our one-on-one with <i>Anchorman 2</i>'s Will Ferrell</div>
                    <div class="overflow" style="margin: 0px; border-radius: 0px; border: 0px rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 212px; height: 100px; overflow: hidden; float: none; position: relative;">
                        <div class="description text-when-feed" style="margin: 0px; border: 0px currentColor; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100px; overflow: auto; padding-right: 24px;">
                            <div class="ExternalClass02301D674D5A4CD29F09A8A903EEE81C">
                                <p style="margin-top: 0px;">Ron Burgundy and the Channel 4 News team are back on the big screen in <a style="color: rgb(80, 134, 222);" href="" target="_blank"><em>Anchorman 2: The Legends Continues</em></a>. With the '70s behind them and the modern "Me" decade upon them, San Diego's top rated foursome kick off the 1980s trying their best to stay classy while grappling with the troubling new phenomenon of 24-hour news channels. Can Ron (<strong>Will Ferrell</strong>), weather man Brick (<strong>Steve Carell</strong>), man on the street Brian (<strong>Paul Rudd</strong>) and sports guy Champ (<strong>David Koechner</strong>) handle this new state of affairs or will the pressure have them breaking down in glass cases of emotion? Our bets are on the latter.Cineplex's own Jolanda Grillone sat down with Ferrell -- the man behind the <em>Anchorman</em> legend -- to talk on his successful partnership with <strong>Adam McKay</strong>, where their idea for this kind-of-a-big-deal sequel came from and just how we can stay classy under pressure. Watch the interview below now:</p>
                                <p style="margin-top: 0px;">See <a style="color: rgb(80, 134, 222);" href="" target="_blank"><em>Anchorman 2: The Legends Continues</em></a><em></em> in theatres starting today.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="news-feed-item">
                <div class="news-data">
                    <div class="title text-when-feed">Stay Classy: Watch our one-on-one with <i>Anchorman 2</i>'s Will Ferrell</div>
                    <div class="overflow" style="margin: 0px; border-radius: 0px; border: 0px rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 212px; height: 100px; overflow: hidden; float: none; position: relative;">
                        <div class="description text-when-feed" style="margin: 0px; border: 0px currentColor; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100px; overflow: auto; padding-right: 24px;">
                            <div class="ExternalClassE36F7671767943EDA4F8E9BB51F87CEC">
                                <p style="margin-top: 0px;">See <a style="color: rgb(80, 134, 222);" href="" target="_blank"><em>Anchorman 2: The Legends Continues</em></a><em></em> in theatres starting today.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="news-feed-item">
                <div class="news-data">
                    <div class="title text-when-feed">Stay Classy: Watch our one-on-one with <i>Anchorman 2</i>'s Will Ferrell</div>
                    <div class="overflow" style="margin: 0px; border-radius: 0px; border: 0px rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 212px; height: 100px; overflow: hidden; float: none; position: relative;">
                        <div class="description text-when-feed" style="margin: 0px; border: 0px currentColor; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100px; overflow: auto; padding-right: 24px;">
                            <div class="ExternalClass1A77CE7AC610487A807D709C76747733">
                                <p style="margin-top: 0px;">See <a style="color: rgb(80, 134, 222);" href="" target="_blank"><em>Anchorman 2: The Legends Continues</em></a><em></em> in theatres starting today.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#main {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:732px;
    height:158px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.item {
    float:left;
    height:140px;
    width: 680px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.news-feed-item {
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    height:138px;
    width: 225px;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    border-right:1px solid #ccc;
    background-color:rgb(243, 243, 243);
}
.news-feed-item .news-data {
    float:left;
    width: 214px;
    padding-left:5px;
}
.news-data {
    font-family:"segoe-regular";
    float:left;
    padding-left:5px;
    color: black;
}
.title {
    font-family:"segoe_uisemibold";
    position:inherit;
    z-index: 200;
    color:#339dde;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:14px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    padding-top:5px;
    background-color:rgb(243, 243, 243);
    width: 212px;
}
.news-item .description {
    float:left;
    z-index:100;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:16px;
}
.news-feed-item .description {
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:16px;
}
/* Slider styling*/
 #full-width-slider {
    width: 100%;
    height:140px;
    color: #000;
}
.fullWidth {
    margin: 0 auto 12px;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function createSlider() {
    $('.royalSlider').royalSlider({
        arrowsNav: true,
        loop: false,
        keyboardNavEnabled: false,
        controlsInside: false,
        imageScaleMode: 'fill',
        arrowsNavAutoHide: true,
        autoScaleSlider: false,
        controlNavigation: 'bullets',
        thumbsFitInViewport: false,
        navigateByClick: true,
        sliderDrag: true,
        sliderTouch: true,
        startSlideId: 0,
        autoPlay: false,
        transitionType: 'move',
        globalCaption: true,
        visibleNearby: {
            enabled: true,
            center: false,
            centerArea: 0.91
        },
        /* size of all images */
        imgWidth: 227,
        imgHeight: 140
    });

    /* Show Navigation Arrows on load */
    $(".rsArrowRight, .rsArrowLeft").removeClass("rsHidden");

    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".rsArrowRight, .rsArrowLeft").addClass("rsHidden");
    }, 1500);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    createSlider();
})
```

What I would like is to hide the overflow that happens, if you compare the behavior with IE8 or Chrome, you will see the difference. Is this an IE10 bug? Plugin bug?

**EDIT** I cannot reproduce the issue in Chrome using the emulator on a different computer. This might be a IE setting problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change `centerArea: 1` in the javascript, like this:

```
centerArea: 1
```

P.S. I think you also want `.main` instead of `#main`

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vwDFa/7/

The 'visible nearby' data makes things visible nearby (as in, the next frame), just like you were experiencing. You can actually remove the whole block if you don't want that.

```
visibleNearby: {
    enabled: true,
    center: false,
    centerArea: 0.91
},
```

More fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vwDFa/8/

Comment: On my site 0.91 is correct for centre area otherwise it becomes off centre. And no I need the visible nearby to be on since I want to show the next slide. I think you misunderstood my question. Look at the image I posted. That Extra text after the arrows shouldn't happen. The next slide should only be visible inside it's container not outside of it.

Comment: Did you change #main to .main in the css?

Comment: That was a typo on my part. Doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: They you will need to put up a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem. Your current jsfiddle seems to be doing what you want. (at least on my chrome browser)

Comment: OK will do once I get home.

Comment: Try putting overflow:hidden on the .main css as well. Worth a shot.

Comment: Once you drag back notice the right edge of the slide/window. You will see it flicker.

Comment: I don't see anything like that on chrome or ie.